# Java8 Sort by 2 fields using method reference

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I have below class :

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    double price;
    // Getters & Setters
}
```

I can compare using lambda like this:

```
Collections.sort(items, (Item o1, Item o2) -> {
            int result = Double.valueOf(o2.getPrice()).compareTo(o1.getPrice());
            if (result == 0) {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
            return result;
        });
```

I want to use **method reference** for comparing elements but I want to compare by name fist and then using price. How can I achieve this?

Also is there a simplified way of using lambda here?

Comment: `Comparator.comparing(Item::getName).thenComparingDouble(Item::getPrice)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Comparator::comparing` and `Comparator::comparingDouble` method to easily create a compartor on the fly:

```
List<Item> items = ...;
items.sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::getName).thenComparingDouble(Item::getPrice));
```